# Using regex to extract string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am receiving strings from an external client and I am trying to perform regex-ing to extract a certain number and status that are embedded in this string. Here’s the examples of the strings that are coming in.

```
data = "< REP 1 INPUT_AUDIO_A ON >"
data = "< REP 1 INPUT_AUDIO_A OFF " 
data = "< REP 2 INPUT_AUDIO_A ON >" 
data = "< REP 2 INPUT_AUDIO_A OFF >"
```

and so on

I am trying to extract `1`, `2` as gate number and the `on` or `off` as status in two different variables. I was able to extract numbers with regex as follows.

```
var gateNumberRegex = /[0-8]/g;
var gateNumber = data.charAt(data.search(gateNumberRegex)); //extract the gate number from string, output is 1 or 2 etc.
```

Not sure how to extract the `on`/`off` status, any pointers?

Comment: Is "INPUT_AUDIO_A" always gonna be there?

Comment: @GermanC Yes, it will always be there and if not, that string is not a match to perform regex-ing so I'd end up ignoring it

Comment: Then give it a shot with `INPUT_AUDIO_A[\s]+([\w+])`

Comment: [Try this](https://regex101.com/r/fEDnQ6/1)

Comment: @GermanC: No need to put single expressions like `\s` or `\w` in square brackets, `INPUT_AUDIO_A\s+(\w+)` is equally fine and more readable.

Comment: @Jan yup, I found two answers by the time I was gonna edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight forward

```
(\d+)\s+INPUT_AUDIO_A\s+(ON|OFF)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/734hK6/1).

---

Broken down, this says:

```
(\d+)         # capture 1+ digits into group 1
\s+           # match 1+ whitespaces
INPUT_AUDIO_A # INPUT_AUDIO_A literally
\s+           # 1+ whitespaces
(ON|OFF)      # ON or OFF
```

Use group `$1` and `$2`, respectively as in this snippet:

```js
var data = 'data = “< REP 1 INPUT_AUDIO_A ON >” or'
var match = data.match(/(\d+)\s+INPUT_AUDIO_A\s+(ON|OFF)/)
console.log(match[1])
console.log(match[2])
```

Comment: Super cool! Need to learn regexes. Any resources to recommend?

Answer (score 1):

By itself, ON/OFF may be found using `/\b(ON|OFF)\b/` but if there may be ON/OFF in another place in those strings, you may go more contextual with `/INPUT_AUDIO_A[\s]+(ON|OFF)/`. Once you apply the regex like this

```
var match = `/\b(ON|OFF)\b/`.exec(yourLine)
```

you may extract the on/off bit with

```
var enabled = match ? match[1] : yourDefaultValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var onOrOffRegex = /INPUT_AUDIO_A ([^\s]+)/g
var onOrOff = data.match(onOrOffRegex)[1]
```

Then you could use the `onOrOff` variable to get the string status of the data.

Answer (score 0):

For your very specific case, assuming the input is "valid", this is the most straight-forward solution:

```
\d+|ON|OFF
```

Output: `'1','ON','1','OFF','2','ON','2','OFF'`

And then you can separate it to "pairs":

```js
var string = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML;
var array = string.match(/\d+|ON|OFF/g);
var result = [];
var print = "";
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
  result += [array[i], array[i + 1]];
  print += "[" + array[i] + ", " + array[i + 1] + "]<BR>"
}

document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = print;
```

```html
<div id="input">
  data = “
    < REP 1 INPUT_AUDIO_A ON>” or data = “
    < REP 1 INPUT_AUDIO_A OFF>” or data = “
    < REP 2 INPUT_AUDIO_A ON>” or data = “
    < REP 2 INPUT_AUDIO_A OFF>”
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be:

`var data = "< REP 1 INPUT_AUDIO_A ON >"`

`var result = data.match(/\b(\d+|ON|OFF)\b/g)`

This will output an array containing the number and the status: `["1", "ON"]`